# Cannot understand iterator behavior in C++

Tags: c++

```
#include<utility>
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<cstdio>
#include<map>
#include<vector>
#include<set>
#define M 100000
using namespace std;

int main() {
    map<char, vector<pair<char,int> > > graph;
    vector<pair<char,int> > vector1;
    vector1.push_back(pair<char,int>('B',4));
    graph['A'] = vector1;
    map<char,int> citydistances;
    citydistances['A'] = 0;

    vector<pair<char,int> >::iterator edge;
    for (map<char,int>::iterator i=citydistances.begin(); i!=citydistances.end(); ++i) {
        vector<pair<char, int> > cities = graph[i->first];
        for (vector<pair<char,int> >::iterator j=cities.begin(); j!=cities.end(); ++j) {
            if (citydistances.find(j->first)==citydistances.end()) {
                edge = j;
                //point 1
                cout<<edge->first<<endl;
            }
        }
    }
    //point 2
    cout<<edge->first<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I've tried to cut short my code as much as possible to focus on the part where the behavior is unexpected. I don't understand why the values of `edge->first` at point 1 and point 2 are different. `edge->first` is 'B' at point 1 but `'\000'` at point 2. Could somebody please help me?

Comment: `cities` is a *copy* of the map element, so it's UB.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`edge = j` (just before point 1),
while `j` is an iterator into the vector `cities`. At point 2 that vector has been destructed, so dereferencing edge (`edge->first`) results in undefined behaviour.

It would be fixed by making `cities` a reference:

```
vector<pair<char, int> > &cities = graph[i->first];
```